# Como personalizo a página de erro 404 no Django?

Tags: javascript, django

Como faço para personalizar a página de error404 do Django?

Tentei colocar:

`handler404 = 'task.views.custom_404'`

no `urls` e

```
def custom_404(request, exception):
    return render(request, '404.html', {}, status=404)
```

no `views.py`

Answer (score 1):

Segundo a [documentação](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/urls/#django.conf.urls.handler404), faltou retornar uma função do tipo `HttpResponseNotFound`.

Dessa forma basta fazer o import dessa função e fazer o tipo de retorno esperado.

```
from django.http import HttpResponseNotFound

def custom_404_view(request, exception=None):
    return HttpResponseNotFound("<h1>!Page not found!</h1>")
```

Em seu `urls.py` o tplt aqui é o nome do módulo que possui as implementações concretas das páginas personalizadas, deve ter a seguinte configuração:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from <tplt>.views import custom_404_view, default
handler404 = custom_404_view
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', default)
]
```

Lembrando que para poder ver a página personalizada, é necessário o modo `debug=False` em seu `settings.py`.

Para ver um exemplo real de implementação sugiro acessar este [repositório](https://github.com/danizavtz/custom404pagedjango)